# Finding the maximum values of a set of local maxima using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to ask a question about finding the maxima of a set of peaks using matplotlib and numpy.

I have been given data containing peaks and asked to calculate the maxima of the set of peaks.

Below is a picture of the peaks.

[image]

I discovered the `find_peaks` [method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) and attempted to solve the problem using this.

I wrote the following block of code in Jupyter:

```
%pylab inline
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

testdata = loadtxt("testdata.dat", usecols=(0,1))
testdata_x = testdata[100:200,0]
testdata_y = testdata[100:200,1]
plot(testdata_x, testdata_y)
show()

peaks = find_peaks(testdata_y)
peaks
```

However, I get the following output for `peaks`:

```
(array([ 7, 12, 36, 40, 65, 69, 93, 97]), {})
```

I cannot understand why I get an output as above and am struggling to find a solution.

I attempted also to pass the following:

```
peaks = find_peaks(testdata_y, testdata_x)
```

but this was to no avail.

How can I sort out the matter?

I have attached the data file here as a download [link](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/847716/testdata.dat) if necessary (hoested on filehosting.org)

Comment: I can see by a naked eye from your numbers and your plot that your `array([ 7, 12, 36, 40, 65, 69, 93, 97])` corresponds to indices of `testdata[100:200]` where maximums are met.

Comment: The same is described in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments say, the values returned by `find_peaks` are the indices (or locations) of the peaks.

To find the values of these peaks, use the peak indices to get the values out of `testdata_y`. Then you can get the max.

```py
%pylab inline
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

testdata = loadtxt("testdata.dat", usecols=(0,1))
testdata_x = testdata[100:200,0]
testdata_y = testdata[100:200,1]
plot(testdata_x, testdata_y)
show()

peaks = find_peaks(testdata_y)
peak_values = testdata_y[peaks[0]]
max_peak = max(peak_values)
```

Comment: Yeah I understood later - I was just too stressed to realise what was going on until I counted the data points later! Many thanks nonetheless!